# Sorting a hashmap

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, treeset

I need to sort a hash map according to the key.The key is a string(so I need to sort it alphabetically) and the value is an integer.
I was trying to search online and found that tree set automatically sorts it once you put it. Could somebody guide me in the right direction as to how I could convert it into a tree set or maybe even if i could just sort it using a hash map.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a TreeMap. You can create a TreeMap using the constructor that takes a Map as parameter.

Comment: You can't sort a HashMap, since a HashMap stores elements unordered. You first have to convert it to another datastructure, like a List/Array/TreeMap etc.

Answer (score 6):

Since hashmaps are unsorted maps by definition you'd need to use another container for that. Depending on your needs there are several options, some being:

1. Use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap` either temporarily or as a replacement. This would be the best option unless you *have* to keep the hashmap.
2. Use a `TreeSet` to sort the keys, then iterate over the keys and extract the values from the `HashMap`.
3. Do the same as in option 2 but fill a new `LinkedHashMap` during iteration. This will result in a map that returns the values in insert order which happens to be sort order due to use of a sorted set. Note that adding elements to the `LinkedHashMap` will append any new elements to the end - `LinkedHashMap` is still ordered by insertion order.

Comment: No, I dont "have" to use a hashmap, I just used it from the start and I realised that its a unsorted map(I'm a bit of a amateur). So, if I replace it with a TreeMap instead, would it get sorted automatically?

Comment: @bawa yes, The things you add to TreeMap are sorted automatically.